# angular material: how to aline in a row 3 input fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I try to put 3 elements in one row

```
                        <ng-form name="voiceForm" novalidate>

                            <div layout="row" layout-padding="">
                                <div layout="column" flex="70">
                                    <div layout="column">




....

    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm ng-if="$ctrl.isAddMode" class="md-inline-form" layout-gt-sm="row">

     <label>ID</label> vp_
      <md-select ng-model="ctrl.id_language" flex-gt-sm>
    <md-option ng-repeat="languageName in $ctrl.languages" ng-value="languageName">
                    {{languageName}}
                  </md-option>
                </md-select>
                _
                <input name="id_freetext" ng-model="$ctrl.id_freetext" flex-gt-sm ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/" ng-change="$ctrl.verifyId()" required>

                <span class='error' ng-if="voiceForm.id_freetext.$error.unique">duplicated</span>
                <span class='error' ng-if="voiceForm.id_freetext.$error.required">required</span>
                <span class='error' ng-if="voiceForm.id_freetext.$error.pattern">alphanumeric only</span>

    </md-input-container>
```

I have tried `"layout=row"` or `inline` like "title and email" are in a row in this [form](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input)

but the elements are still in a column.

[image]

how can i fix this?

Comment: Can you add it's parent elements (div's) also so that it helps to figure out.

Comment: @RajathMS but even if the parent layout is `coloumn` it shouldn't effect the elements in the `md-input-container` no?

Comment: as it plays around flexbox, sometimes parent classes plays a role. and the code snippet you have added is not making sense to judge over that.